# How to use dynamic height of window in electron?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, desktop-application

I am developing desktop application using electron + react js.
I need to create second window which can not be resized and should have height depends on content
[image]

So i need window with can be in 2 variants based on length of content. Is it possible with electron?

Comment: check this https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open